# The name 'Maps' does not exist in the current context error using google maps in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to integrate a Google map in an asp.net application, but I get the following error:

> The name " 'Maps' does not exist in the current context "

Here is the code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Map";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Map an Address</title>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Map an Address</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <div>
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
            <input style="width: 300px" type="text" name="address" value="@Request["England"]"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Map It!" />
           </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    @if(IsPost) {
        @Maps.GetGoogleHtml(Request.Form["England"],
            width: "400",
            height: "400")
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just add `@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers` at the top of your page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either:

1. Add a 'using' statement to specify the DLL that "Maps" belongs to
2. Fully namespace your Maps class

e.g. (bearing in mind this is not the exact name of your DLL!)

```
@if(IsPost) {
    @Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Maps.GetGoogleHtml(....
```

Comment: Now I get the following error: "The type or namespace name 'Maps' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Have you right clicked on your project > References folder and done Add Reference > Microsoft.Web.Helpers?

Comment: Have to download `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` from Nuget Package?